# When executing playbook which suppose to create resource group give error while executing playbook

Tags: azure, ansible

I have develop a playbook with roles which will create resource group on Azure cloud.
Below is the directory structure.

```
prhinge1@DESKTOP-F8RMF14:~/pits-shared-service$ cd roles
prhinge1@DESKTOP-F8RMF14:~/pits-shared-service/roles$ ls
netinfracreator
prhinge1@DESKTOP-F8RMF14:~/pits-shared-service/roles$ tree netinfracreator
netinfracreator
├── README.md
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
├── tests
│   ├── inventory
│   └── test.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml

8 directories, 8 files
```

tasks/main.yml contains below code

```yaml
    ---
    # tasks file for netinfracreator
    - name: Create resource group if doesn't exist
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
         name: "{{ resource_group }}"
         location: "{{ location }}"
```

vars/main.yml - variables declare in this file.

```
---
# vars file for netinfracreator
resource_group: "test_ansible_resourcegrp"
location: "eastus"
```

Below is the main playbook file (netinfracreator-role.yml) which calls the role.

```yaml
    ---
    - name: User netinfracreator role playbook
      hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      collections:
       - azure.azcollection
      become_user: root
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
    
      roles:
       - role: netinfracreator
```

In addition I have store service principal credential in /home//.azure/credentials files.

pythone version used is as below

```
prhinge1@DESKTOP-F8RMF14:~/pits-shared-service$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

When I am executing playbook I am getting below errors. Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

```
prhinge1@DESKTOP-F8RMF14:~/pits-shared-service$ sudo ansible-playbook netinfracreator-role.yml --check
[sudo] password for prhinge1:

PLAY [User netinfracreator role playbook] *****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [netinfracreator : Create resource group if doesn't exist] *******************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.azure/azureProfile.json'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/_session.py\", line 39, in load\n    with codecs_open(self.filename, 'r', encoding=self._encoding) as f:\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py\", line 905, in open\n    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.azure/azureProfile.json'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622712598.829142-71872954787953/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622712598.829142-71872954787953/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622712598.829142-71872954787953/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.cloud.azure.azure_rm_resourcegroup', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 207, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 97, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 87, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/modules/cloud/azure/azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 291, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/modules/cloud/azure/azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 287, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/modules/cloud/azure/azure_rm_resourcegroup.py\", line 167, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 341, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 1145, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 1378, in _get_credentials\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_lhvkhayb/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 1289, in _get_azure_cli_credentials\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/azure/common/credentials.py\", line 46, in get_azure_cli_credentials\n    profile = get_cli_profile()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/azure/common/credentials.py\", line 28, in get_cli_profile\n    ACCOUNT.load(os.path.join(azure_folder, 'azureProfile.json'))\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/_session.py\", line 42, in load\n    self.save()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/_session.py\", line 46, in save\n    with codecs_open(self.filename, 'w', encoding=self._encoding) as f:\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py\", line 905, in open\n    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.azure/azureProfile.json'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: How much clearer could the error message have been than `No such file or directory: '/root/.azure/azureProfile.json'`?

Comment: Using simple play book same task can execute successfully and create resource on azure but while executing role base approach then only this error occurred. I am new to Ansible and exploring this approach so not able to understand connection of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue. In netinfracreator-role.yml , I used

```
become_user: root
become: true
become_method: sudo
```

Which is actually not required. Because of this it force me to run playbook using **sudo** command. because of this it always search azureProfile.json file in root however it is in my user folder.
So to resolve this I removed all **become** parameters from play book and execute the play book without **sudo** and it worked.